# Sorting nodes based on URL and taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy-terms, ubercart, views

I have products that are being sold through Ubercart - there are different kinds and different sub-kinds of products. These types are based on taxonomy so a product will be type "Card" and sub-type "Childrens".

For instance I want .com/cards to show all products that match "Cards" and I want .com/cards/children to show all products that match both "Cards" and "Childrens".

For each type and subtype I want there to be a page that shows only suitable products - I can do this using Views but I have to set up a filter that matches the correct types/sub-types. Since I plan on adding various types/sub-types in the future and don't want to add new views for each individual type is there a way to relate this to the URL in some manner?

How do I go about doing this with Contextual Filters? I know this is possible but I think I'm just having a total brain fart over it.